# Leaflet Esri geocoding on Angular not import Geocoding class

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, esri, esri-leaflet-geocoder

I try to use the Geocoding form esri-leaflet library on Angular project but I have import class problem.

This is my component code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { latLng, tileLayer, layerGroup, marker, Layer, Control, circle, polygon, Map } from 'leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as esri from 'esri-leaflet';
import GeocodeService from 'esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder';


@Component({
  selector: 'abd-map',
  templateUrl: './abd-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abd-map.component.scss']
})
export class AbdMapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

 }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void{


    const openStreetMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    const googleMap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    });


    const map = L.map('map', {
        center: [39.61, -105.02],
        zoom: 13,
        layers: [openStreetMap, googleMap]
    });

    const baseMaps = {
      'openStreetMap': openStreetMap,
      'googleMap': googleMap
  };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);


    const searchControl = esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);


  }



}
```

When I run "ng serve" I have this error:

ERROR in ./src/app/abd-map/abd-map.component.ts 41:30-44
"export 'Geocoding' (imported as 'esri') was not found in 'esri-leaflet'

Someone can help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should import:

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css";
import "esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder";
import * as ELG from "esri-leaflet-geocoder";
```

and then initialize the plugin like this:

```
  const searchControl = new ELG.Geosearch();
  const results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

    searchControl
      .on("results", function (data) {
        results.clearLayers();
        for (let i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
        }
      })
      .addTo(map);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-esri-leaflet-geocoder-on-angualr-zjxfe)

Comment: ok thanks, now with this import my code works but I have also problem with reverse geocoding.


    const geocodeService = esriGeocoder.geocodeService();

    map.on('click', e => {

      debugger

      geocodeService.reverse().latlng(e.latlng).run(res => {

      });


    });


error TS2339: Property 'latlng' does not exist on type 'LeafletEvent'.

Comment: That is another question my friend. Please ask it in a new thread and accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.